# How to iterate each element in list with all the others

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a list of *n* elements and I want to check if any element *x* in list can be achieved by using one of the other elements (*y*) with the expression:

```
x =  y + 1 - 2*(x % 2)
```

To do that I need to iterate each element *x* in the list with all the others. I got that by nesting two *for loops*:

```
_list = [8,2,0,1]
for x in _list:
    for y in _list:
        if(x == y + 1 - 2*(x % 2)):
            # Do something
        else: pass
```

Obviously the problems with this solution are that: it uses two loops instead of one; every element iterate with itself; and pairs *(x,y)* will be checked twice.

Are there any other ways to do that with less code and more efficiently?

Comment: Your loop will check the pair (a,b) and the pair (b,a), but don't you have to check both those pairs?  Your condition isn't symmetric, so you need to check both ways, no?

Comment: isn't getting all pairs of the form (x,y) from a collection basically a O(n^2) time operation no matter what you do?

Comment: You could also apply some math. If `x` is even, then the condition is true when `y == x-1`. If `x` is odd, then the condition is true when `y == x+1` - which means it also holds with `x` and `y` swapped. Thus, you just need to check whether the list contains an odd number and the next higher number, which you can do with a `set` of odd numbers and one loop.

Comment: @NedBatchelder the condition is symmetric for any x and y constrained to integers set. See: `0 == 1 + 1 - 2*(1 % 2) == 2-2` and also `1 == 0 + 1 - 2*(0 % 2) == 1+0`

Comment: @RodrigoMartins ok, i stand corrected.

Comment: Use [`itertools.combinations`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations).

Comment: @BrenBarn That is just what I was looking for. Sorry asking a duplicate, I searched before asking but I didn't found that Q&A you pointed. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lets break your main question down a bit further.

```
x = y + 1 (if x is even)
x = y - 1 ( if x is odd)
```

Now, from the above, its fairly obvious that if x is odd, then y is even, and vice versa.

Also, x and y are just 1 units away. In other words, abs(x-y) == 1. Your solution would then simply boil down to finding all the numbers that satisfy this condition. You can also observe that x & y are swappable.

This post does not answer "less code" part but answers efficiently part. ;)

---

Update: I take the first half of the last sentence back.

```
>>> from itertools import chain
>>> s =  [8,2,0,1]
>>> s1 = sorted(s)
>>> list(chain(*(((x,y),(y,x)) for (x,y) in zip(s1, s1[1:]) if y-x == 1)))
[(0, 1), (1, 0), (1, 2), (2, 1)]
```

Answer (score 2):

You only need to check elements after the current one

```
for i in xrange(len(_list)):
  x = _list[i]
  for j in xrange(i+1,len(_list)):
    y = _list[j]
    if (..):
      # do something
```